What specific permissions are required to make a request to Google's Identity Toolkit when using multi-tenancy to disable user signup?
I am making a request to disable user signup on a firebase multi-tenant system.
The payload is:
{"client": {"permissions": {"disabled_user_signup": true,"disabled_user_deletion": false }}}

With url: https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v2/projects/%s/tenants/%s?updateMask=client
method: Patch
Oauth scope: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase
The access token for the service account works and the operation is successful if the service account has the Owner role. I haven't been able to find any other combination of roles or permissions that will work.
I've tried the typical candidates: Firebase Authentication Admin, Service Token Creator, Firebase Admin SDK Administrator, Cloud functions Admin, etc.
What is baffling is that I am able to create tenants, add sign-in options etc. without issues with the same token.
The error received is:

Error getting access token for service account: 400 Bad Request POST https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token {"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Invalid JWT Signature."}, iss: firebase-xxxx@xxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com
com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthException: Error getting access token for service account: 400 Bad Request
POST https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token


The correct permission is:
serviceusage.services.use

